# Github split directory into two folders on its own accord

Tags: github, google-cloud-run

I've been working on a project, and for no reason, after a merge, our Github got split into two folders - Exeplore and ExePlore. The peculiar thing is that it's only split into these two folders on github.com. If you download the repo, it's correctly organised into one folder. You can push and pull from it, and only get the Exeplore folder, which is fine, no files are lost, but the only issue now is trying to set up continuous deployment on google cloud run. It only downloads one file from the github, causing errors. If anyone knows how to reformat the folders into one, it would be much appreciated.

It seems that the folders are randomly assigned into one folder or the other, as half our HTML has been put into Exeplore and the other half ExePlore, and with other files scattered about.

[Here's the link to the repo](https://github.com/Pierre-siddall/Exeplore)
Any advice would be much appreciated!
Thanks,
Jenni

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Once you fix this problem, it might return. This is a character **case** problem. Windows ignores case in paths, Linux does not. Check how the **git** clients are setup. Example: one system might be configured to ignore case and another respects case:

```
git config core.ignorecase false
```

[git config - corse.ignoreCase](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-config/2.14.6#Documentation/git-config.txt-coreignoreCase)

Then you will need to **move** each file with the wrong case. This git client must be configured to not ignore case.

```
git mv ExePlore/file1 Exeplore
```

[git mv](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-mv)

Comment: Ah, figured it must've been something like that. There's six of us working on it, so somewhere along the line something happened. If we have time, I'll try your answer. Thank you!!